# Apache ANT : get doesn't support the nested "header" element

Tags: ant

I am trying to use the get task in my build.xml and has target something like this

```
<target name="download" >
        <get src="URL"
             dest="dist">
            <header name="aa" value="123"/>
        </get>
    </target>
```

When I execute the above target I am getting the error as

`get doesn't support the nested "header" element.`

I am using ant version as 1.10.1
Can someone help me to resolve this.

Comment: It works in 1.10.2... I can't figure out why, but header is not an allowed element of get in 1.10.1.  Can you change to 1.10.2 or newer?

Comment: Yeah I just upgraded to latest version of ant and it works. Thanks.